# What is the default vim colorscheme?

Tags: 10.10, vim

I really like the default `vim` colorscheme in 10.10 but I can't figure out what it's called -- I want to turn it on for my Debian box as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are on a light terminal, the default is `peachpuff`.

If you are on a dark terminal, the default is `ron`.

You can tell which you have by typing `:set background?`.

(Vim guesses whether your terminal has a dark or light background based on the value of the `TERM` environment variable.)

I found this answer by going ":color <kbd>Tab</kbd>" and choosing each option, then comparing it to the default.

Comment: it could be elflord I suppose but it looks like ron. thanks!

Comment: Actually, the default colorscheme is named "default".  You can use it by calling `:colorscheme default`.  Peachpuff and ron are different from the default.

Comment: There are different defaults depending on whether your terminal is classified as having a dark or light background.  `default` and `peachpuff` seem to be identical to me, but if you're on a dark terminal, doing `:colorscheme default` does not give you the default colorscheme, whereas `:colorscheme ron` looks the same as what you get automatically.

Comment: Actually, `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/syntax/syncolor.vim` seems to be involved as well.

Comment: Thanks Mikel. The colorscheme default was not giving intended result because some one down in my vimrc the xterm background setting was set to "dark" which was causing all cyan and yellow colors to be picked up. As soon as I commented them out it worked.

Answer (score 10):

It's **/usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/default.vim**. On the Debian side, `mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors` and then copy *default.vim* to that new directory. Open your ~/.vimrc and add the line `colorscheme default` to use it all the time, or `colorscheme ubuntu` if you renamed the *default.vim* to *ubuntu.vim*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at my ubuntu box, at the moment... but by default the vim colorschemes are stored to the "/usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/" directory. The default scheme should be named unimaginatively "default.vim"

In vim you can use ":help colorscheme" to see how to best enable to color scheme in your debian box. I would recommend that, you would install the colorscheme in your .vim profile directory.